# Element <a href="javascript:void(0);" ng-click="openNav()">...</a> is not clickable at point (35, 37)

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am getting this error after login to the landing page and i am unable to identify the element through the xpath.
I have tried all the solutions available through Surfing Like
but nothing is working for me
Exception in thread 
"main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException:  unknown error: Element ... is not clickable at point (35, 37). Other element would receive the click:

Comment: 1.driver.manage().window().maximize();

Comment: 2.WebElement element = driver.findElement(By("element"));
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.moveToElement(element).click().perform();

Comment: JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
 // if the element is on top.
js.executeScript("scroll(250, 0)");

// if the element is on bottom.
js.executeScript("scroll(0, 250)");

Comment: You can also try the below using X or Y position

        WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id(""));
        JavascriptExecutor js =(JavascriptExecutor)driver;
        js.executeScript("window.scrollTo(0,"element.getLocation().x+")");
        element.click();
Or

        WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id(""));
        JavascriptExecutor js =(JavascriptExecutor)driver;
        js.executeScript("window.scrollTo(0,"element.getLocation().y+")");
        element.click();

Comment: but nothing is working for me